# Reverse Long Pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
self.minute_olhc_df
                               timestamp    open    high     low   close    volume  percentage_change  dollar_volume
timestamp                                                                                                           
2023-04-12 08:00:00  2023-04-12 08:00:00  0.4451  0.7200  0.4451  0.5800   32664.0          48.760331   1.674193e+04
2023-04-12 08:01:00  2023-04-12 08:01:00  0.5700  0.8800  0.5441  0.7500  245138.0          81.818182   1.785330e+05
2023-04-12 08:02:00  2023-04-12 08:02:00  0.7613  0.8899  0.6800  0.8786  226893.0          83.863636   3.645739e+05
2023-04-12 08:03:00  2023-04-12 08:03:00  0.8786  0.9500  0.8140  0.9350  249540.0          96.280992   5.908568e+05
2023-04-12 08:04:00  2023-04-12 08:04:00  0.9399  0.9870  0.8949  0.9142  264829.0         103.925620   8.363665e+05
...                                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...       ...                ...            ...
2023-04-12 19:55:00  2023-04-12 19:55:00  0.8300  0.8300  0.8300  0.8300     462.0          71.487603   9.644505e+07
2023-04-12 19:56:00  2023-04-12 19:56:00  0.8390  0.8489  0.8217  0.8217   13363.0          75.392562   9.645615e+07
2023-04-12 19:57:00  2023-04-12 19:57:00  0.8350  0.8350  0.8350  0.8350     583.0          72.520661   9.645663e+07
2023-04-12 19:58:00  2023-04-12 19:58:00  0.8337  0.8337  0.8329  0.8329    1635.0          72.252066   9.645800e+07
2023-04-12 19:59:00  2023-04-12 19:59:00  0.8218  0.8397  0.8205  0.8205    9239.0          73.491736   9.646558e+07

[673 rows x 8 columns]
```

Here is a python dataframe. I have two variables, i.e. `morning_high_price` and `morning_high_time`. They are the highest price between 9:30AM and noon and the time it occurred. How can I get all the moments where the prices were the same as `morning_high_price` or within 2% lower between noon and 4:30PM?

**ChatGPT solution:**

```
# Set the time range
start_time = pd.Timestamp('2023-04-12 12:00:00')
end_time = pd.Timestamp('2023-04-12 16:30:00')

# Get the morning high price and time
morning_high_price = self.minute_olhc_df['high']['2023-04-12 09:30:00':'2023-04-12 12:00:00'].max()
morning_high_time = self.minute_olhc_df['high']['2023-04-12 09:30:00':'2023-04-12 12:00:00'].idxmax()

# Filter the dataframe to the time range and where the price is within 2% lower
filtered_df = self.minute_olhc_df[(self.minute_olhc_df['timestamp'] > start_time) & (self.minute_olhc_df['timestamp'] < end_time) & (self.minute_olhc_df['high'] >= morning_high_price*0.98) & (self.minute_olhc_df['high'] <= morning_high_price)]

# Get the moments where the prices were the same as morning_high_price and within 2% lower
result = filtered_df[filtered_df['high'] == morning_high_price]
```

This is the solution from chat gpt, but this is really not what I want. It gives me the highest price between noon and 4:30PM, but this is not what I expected. Roughly, I just need to know if the morning highest price has been revisited in PM and very close to be.

Comment: In addition, Please edit your question title to reflect your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took data from `yfinance` in one day. In this case, the name of the `High` column is your `high` column (if you will correct for your data). To filter datetime, I use dates, because using `slices` for indexes '2023-04-12 09:30:00':'2023-04-12 12:00:00', it may turn out that, for example, the first line at 12 o'clock will be '2023-04-12 12:01:00'.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

minute_olhc_df = yf.download(tickers='MSFT', period='1d', interval='1m')

morning_high_time = minute_olhc_df.loc[(minute_olhc_df.index >= '2023-04-27 09:30:00')
                                       & (minute_olhc_df.index < '2023-04-27 12:00:00'), 'High'].idxmax()
morning_high_price = minute_olhc_df.loc[morning_high_time, 'High']
```

To find out if the maximum has been exceeded. Which gets rows greater than the maximum. The first line is the first maximum exceeded.

```
more_max = minute_olhc_df.loc[(minute_olhc_df.index >= '2023-04-27 12:00:00') &
                              (minute_olhc_df.index <= '2023-04-27 16:30:00')
                              & (minute_olhc_df['High'] > morning_high_price), 'High']
```

The index of the first excess can be obtained like this:

```
more_max.index[0]
```

If you need a maximum minus 2%, then replace the condition with:

```
max_minus2percent = minute_olhc_df.loc[(minute_olhc_df.index >= '2023-04-27 12:00:00') &
                                       (minute_olhc_df.index <= '2023-04-27 16:30:00')
                                       & (minute_olhc_df['High'] > morning_high_price * 0.98), 'High']
```

And speaking of GPT: `filtered_df[filtered_df['high'] == morning_high_price]`
this finds a maximum equal to the morning. I admit this option, the maximum will be more than the morning but not equal to it, then there will be no result.